# Import HTML information to SQL(there I will use C#)

Tags: html, sql, sql-server

I have HTML page, CSS and JS files. There are lists on page ( ul with different IDs). I need to send it or import to SQL database and then make some requires. I will work in Visual Studio, using C#. Is there any methods? I found a lot of information about importing a table from HTML. Or methods are similar for lists and tables?
And other question: in what type of file I need to write code in Visual Studio?

I’m sorry for such stupid questions, SQL is very new for me. Or maybe you can recommend what books or articles I can read?

Comment: The question is too broad to answer. You might find [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/874739/How-to-Insert-HTML-Table-Data-into-SQL-Server-in-a) useful since it covers most of the aspects you need know in order to achieve what you want

Comment: You can check out a library called CSQuery, and it let's you read into an object a HTML DOM, and then construct the aprropriate queries to insert the data into your SQL server